# Chaining Rails 3 scopes in has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, associations, chaining, kaminari

Is this doable?

I have the following scope:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base

scope :with_tag, lambda{ |tag| joins(:tags).where('tags.name = ?', tag.name)
                                           .group('things.id') }

def withtag_search(tags)
  tags.inject(scoped) do |tagged_things, tag|
    tagged_things.with_tag(tag) 
  end
end
```

I get a result if there's a single tag in the array of tags passed in with `Thing.withtag_search(array_of_tags)` but if I pass multiple tags in that array I get an empty relation as the result. In case it helps:

```
Thing.withtag_search(["test_tag_1", "test_tag_2"])

SELECT "things".* 
FROM "things" 
INNER JOIN "things_tags" ON "things_tags"."thing_id" = "things"."id" 
INNER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."id" = "things_tags"."tag_id" 
WHERE (tags.name = 'test_tag_1') AND (tags.name = 'test_tag_2') 
GROUP BY things.id

=> [] # class is ActiveRecord::Relation
```

whereas

```
Thing.withtag_search(["test_tag_1"])

SELECT "things".* 
FROM "things" 
INNER JOIN "things_tags" ON "things_tags"."thing_id" = "things"."id" 
INNER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."id" = "things_tags"."tag_id" 
WHERE (tags.name = 'test_tag_1') 
GROUP BY things.id

=> [<Thing id:1, ... >, <Thing id:2, ... >] # Relation including correctly all 
                                            # Things with that tag
```

I want to be able to chain these relations together so that (among other reasons) I can use the Kaminari gem for pagination which only works on relations not arrays - so I need a scope to be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also ran into this problem. The problem is not Rails, the problems is definitely MySQL:

Your SQL will create following temporary JOIN-table (only neccesary fields are shown):

```
+-----------+-------------+---------+------------+
| things.id | things.name | tags.id | tags.name  |
+-----------+-------------+---------+------------+
|     1     |     ...     |    1    | test_tag_1 |
+-----------+-------------+---------+------------+
|    1      |     ...     |    2    | test_tag_2 |
+-----------+-------------+---------+------------+
```

So instead joining all `Tag`s to one specific `Thing`, it generates one row for each `Tag`-`Thing` combination (If you don't believe, just run `COUNT(*)` on this SQL statement).
The problem is that you query criteria looks like this: `WHERE (tags.name = 'test_tag_1') AND (tags.name = 'test_tag_2')` which will be checked against each of this rows, and never will be true. It's not possible for `tags.name` to equal both `test_tag_1` and `test_tag_2` at the same time!

The standard SQL solution is to use the SQL statement `INTERSECT`... but unfortunately not with MySQL.

The best solution is to run `Thing.withtag_search` for each of your tags, collect the returning objects, and select only objects which are included in each of the results, like so:

```
%w[test_tag_1 test_tag_2].collect do |tag|
  Thing.withtag_search(tag)
end.inject(&:&)
```

If you want to get this as an `ActiveRecord` relation you can probably do this like so:

```
ids = %w[test_tag_1 test_tag_2].collect do |tag|
  Thing.withtag_search(tag).collect(&:id)
end.inject(&:&)
Things.where(:id => ids)
```

The other solution (which I'm using) is to cache the tags in the `Thing` table, and do MySQL boolean search on it. I will give you more details on this solution if you want.

Anyways I hope this will help you. :)

Comment: cheers - this looks helpful, and thanks for identifying the problem...  i will try the above

Answer (score 0):

This is rather complicated at a glance, but based on your SQL, you want:

> WHERE (tags.name IN ( 'test_tag_1', 'test_tag_2'))

I haven't dealt much with Rails 3, but if you can adjust your JOIN appropriately, this should fix your issue.  Have you tried a solution akin to:

```
 joins(:tag).where('tags.name IN (?), tags.map { |tag| tag.name })
```

This way, you will JOIN the way you are expecting (UNION instead of INTERSECTION).  I hope this is a helpful way of thinking about this problem.

Comment: Tried it.  No, this gives me the list of all things with EITHER tag not both tags :-( ...that being said at least it's returning a scope so that's useful for the functionality where I want to search by any of the entered tags - so thanks for that :-) ...now I need to see if I can make it so that I can get a scope out that lets me narrow down by having to have ALL of the tags entered... any thoughts?

Comment: Ohh, rails is combining your JOINs?  How about making the joins unique beyond what Rails will detect?  Instead of joins(:tags), try joins('JOIN tags t1 ON t1.id = things_tags.id WHERE t1.name = #{tag.name}').  Again, I've been using Rails 2 not 3, so I can't get the syntax perfect.  Specifying the joins by hand will definitely complete this puzzle!

Answer (score 0):

Don't seem to be able to find a solution to this problem.  So, instead of using Kaminari and rolling my own tagging I've switched to Acts-as-taggable-on and will-paginate